# What do I do with the "extra" traveler wire when removing a 3way switch?

Tags: electrical, multiway-switch

I have a three-way switch that controls an outdoor flood light.  I'm going to replace the outdoor light with a ring camera/floodlight, so I don't want the switch to control the power anymore. I just want in power all the time.

My plan is to just spice the hot wire to one of the travelers, right through to the other switch and have full power.  By my math, however, there will be an "extra" wire because one of the travelers will be unused.  Do I just put wire nuts on the ends and leave it?

Answer (score 4):

> Do I just put wire nuts on the ends and leave it?

Exactly, cap on both ends and leave it unpowered. You can add in a label for the next person understand what it was and why it's capped.

Comment: Labelling it is advice I wish people had followed in my house. +1 for that.